# Why does DISTINCT change case of literal string

Tags: ms-access, oledb, jet

I have following simplified query against an Access Database:

- Build table: `CREATE TABLE test (id TEXT)`
- Populate: `INSERT INTO test VALUES ('4711')`
- Query:

```sql
SELECT
  id, 
  'value',
  'Value'
FROM 
  test
```

yields

| id | Expr1001 | Expr1002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 | value | **Value** |

Now the same query with `DISTINCT` changes the case of the second literal string:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  id, 
  'value',
  'Value'
FROM 
  test
```

yields

| id | Expr1001 | Expr1002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 | value | **value** |

The Outcome is the same no matter if the query comes via OleDb or directly via MS Access. How come that the database engine changes a literal value? I understand that jet sql ist pretty strange sometimes - but this looks to me like a bug. Or is this behavior described somewhere?

Comment: Shoot - does anybody know why the table is drawn correctly in the draft and looks like this when posted?

Comment: Newlines before tables, CommonMark doesn't process stuff correctly if it's not preceded by a newline. Get a bug when trying to ask about a bug ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly speculation, but what I think is happening is the following:

`SELECT DISTINCT x` is equal to `SELECT x GROUP BY x` and converted to it.

Columns in `GROUP BY` are de-duplicated, `'value'` is equal to `'Value'` according to the collation rules, thus only the first occurrence is processed.

For each column, it's either a constant (calculated once), an aggregate column (calculated for each group), or a group column. Since `'value'` is in the `GROUP BY` and `'Value'` is equal to `'value'`, these are both mapped to the group `'value'`

We can see this behaviour too when grouping by individual columns:

```sql
SELECT
  id, 
  'value',
  'Value'
FROM 
  test
GROUP BY
  id
```

No 'value' in the GROUP BY clause, parsed as expressions

| id | Expr1001 | Expr1002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 | value | **Value** |

```sql
SELECT
  id, 
  'value',
  'Value'
FROM 
  test
GROUP BY
  id, 'valuE'
```

`'value'` and `'valuE'` are equal, thus Expr1001 is a group column `'valuE`, same goes for `'Value'`

| id | Expr1001 | Expr1002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 | valuE | valuE |

The string from the `GROUP BY` clause is used, even though neither strings use that capitalization.

As far as I know, this behaviour is not documented, however. What is documented is that capitalization is ignored when evaluating groups, e.g. you can do `SELECT ID, MAX(SomeColumn) FROM MyTable GROUP BY id` and Access doesn't complain that there's no `ID` column in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it's weird this applies to constants and `DISTINCT` as well. The obvious workaround is: don't group by constants, use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` when you have a `SELECT` clause with constants.

If we compare this behaviour to T-SQL, it doesn't allow constants in the `GROUP BY` part, and thus doesn't experience this behavior. `GROUP BY id, 'valuE'` is not valid T-SQL.

Comment: Sounds plausible even though it may just be speculation. 
Unless someone comes up with any documentation about this behavior this becomes the accepted answer.